# Scilab installation tcl tk configure not working

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, tcl, scilab

I am installing Scilab 4.1.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 manually. I entered the folder and pressed ./configure but after some steps it shows

```
configure: error: header file tcl.h has been found for 8.4*  but no corresponding tcl library (ie libtcl8.4.so)
```

How to resolve this problem? Directly installing Scilab will install the latest version of Scilab but i need to install previous versions.

Comment: You need to install libctl8.4, try finding it through symaptic

Comment: installed but still not working

Comment: Which did you install? libtcl-dev?

Comment: Is there a good reason for not just using the pre-built version of Scilab?